# How to combine signals in Boost Signals2?

Tags: c++, boost, signals-slots, boost-signals2

How would I combine two signals of the same type?

Let's say I have two signals with one connection each, `foo` and `bar`.

```
boost::signals2::signal<void ()> foo;
foo.connect([]{
  std::cout << "Hello from foo!" << std::endl;
});

boost::signals2::signal<void ()> bar;
bar.connect([]{
  std::cout << "Hello from bar!" << std::endl;
});
```

How would I combine the two already created signals later so that `foo` contains both slots?

I can use anything from boost and C++14 or later.

Comment: Do you really need to declare the second signal? Cant you just attach 2 slots to foo?

Comment: The example above is an over simplification of my actual problem. I've got many many signals all over a complex control system, and if I could combine signals after they were initialized it would be convenient.

Comment: As `signal`s are callable objects, shouldn't `foo.connect(bar);` just work?